# Rewriting URL in .htaccess with multiple values

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have rewritten the URL

"123.com/search.php" to "123.com/search" using the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^search$ search.php
```

Its worked for me.But, for "123.com/search.php?cat=something" to "123.com/search/something" using rule

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?cat=$1
```

not working.

It shows error like

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://123.com/search/styles/common.css".`

`Resource interpreted as Scripts but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://123.com/search/scripts/common.js".`

I have that css & js files in 123.com/styles and 123.com/scripts directories.

Also I need help on the rewritting URL 123.com/search.php?cat=something&filter=subcat to 123.com/search/something/subcat

Comment: Use this: `RewriteRule ^search/((?!styles/|scripts/).*)$ search.php?cat=$1`

Comment: @hjpotter92 I got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies inside your HTML. You probably have stylesheets and JavaScript files linked like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/common.css">
<script src="scripts/common.js"></script>
```

These (and all similar) URLs must be changed to absolute URLs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/common.css">
<script src="/scripts/common.js"></script>
```

**Explanation:**

When you are on the search page, the URL of the search page would be:

```
http://123.com/search/
```

When the browser fetches this page it will encounter relative URLs which translate to these URLs:

```
http://123.com/search/styles/common.css
http://123.com/search/scripts/common.js
```

Both of those URLs will be rewritten by the server as:

```
http://123.com/search/search.php?cat=styles/common.css
http://123.com/search/search.php?cat=scripts/common.js
```